# Sub-algebra such that Wigner (-Weyl) transform is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, quantum-mechanics

The Wigner distribution of an operator $A$ is given by

$$
W_A(x,p) :=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R} \! dy \, \langle x+y/2| A | x-y/2 \rangle \, e^{ipy}, 
$$

and associates a function in phase space to an operator on a Hilbert space. See for example [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution).

I used the convention that $\hbar=1$ although in issues about quantization it is standard to re-insert it. However my question is for fixed $\hbar$.

Namely, what is the (a) largest  sub-algebra of operators for which the Wigner transform is *exactly* an homomorphism. Can one get more than the abelian algebra of differential operators (or multiplication operators)?

Comment: $A$ is a linear map $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}) $ and $\langle f| A | g \rangle = \langle Ag,f\rangle $. For $A$ a convolution operator then $(A f(.+c))(x) = (Af)(x+c)$ and $\widehat{Af}(p) = \hat{a}(p) \hat{f}(p)$  so that $\langle A(f(.+y/2)),f(.-y/2)\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (Af)(x+y/2) \overline{f(x-y/2)}dx= (Af) \ast f^*(y)$ where $f^*(y) = \overline{f}(-y)$

Comment: And hence $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R}\langle f(.+y/2)| A | f(.-y/2) \rangle  e^{ipy}dy = \widehat{Af \ast f^*}(p)=\hat{a}(p) |\hat{f}(p)|^2$ and 

$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{R}\langle f(.+y/2)| A_2A+A_3 | f(.-y/2) \rangle =(\hat{a_2}(p)\hat{a}(p)+\hat{a_3}(p)) |\hat{f}(p)|^2$. Clearly it doesn't hold outside of **convolution operators**.

Comment: @reuns thanks, would you post that as an answer (possibly with a few comments)?

Comment: @reuns what kind of convolution operators are you talking about exactly? I mean, do you allow for convolution with distributions?

Comment: To be clear, you are asking about the maximal set of operators for whose Wigner images the $\hbar$ dependence drops out of the [Moyal star products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_product) of the set?